# Which verb to use with noun “action”?

Tags: verbs, vocabulary, technology

In technical manual how would you write: “to run the default action press the button” or to *launch* the default action? Or to *activate*? Or something else?

Comment: It depends on which metaphor best fits. Processing a batch of accounts: run. Rocket: launch. You can also start, initiate or trigger default actions where appropriate.

Comment: There are many different ways of expressing this. It depends entirely on context, the style guide being followed, and personal choice.

Comment: All of the options you listed should be correct! I would pick which one you use based on the context.

Comment: To *perform* the default action...

Comment: Sorry to point out, that doesn't belong to English Language Users but to some other forum dedicated to interface design.

If it did belong here, you'd first need to explain what kind of "default action" you were talking about; how it related to other, unspecified variables and perhaps, a host of other things.

As it is, Global Charm's "perform" sounds like your best choice.